# Javascript: How to open a form with fields filled with parameters?

Tags: javascript, jstl

I'd like to open a form with its fields filled with data corresponding to a certain record.

Example:

- Supose a certain form:

  ## Dogs

  ```
          <table id="tabledogs" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
              <thead>
                  <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <c:forEach var="dog" items="${sessionScope.dogs}">
                      <tr>
                          <td width="50%" align="left">${dog.id}</td>
                          <td width="50%" align="left">${dog.name </td>
                          <td><button id="update">Update</button> </td>
                      </tr>
                  </c:forEach>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
  ```
- I'd like to open the following form with the corresponding dog data within it (there's other form configurations not showed here for space-saving):

  ```
      <form>
          <fieldset>

              <label for="id">ID</label> 
              <input type="text" name="id" id="id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /> 

              <label for="name">Name</label> 
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /> 

          </fieldset>
      </form>
  </div>
  ```

For while I have the following JavaScript, wich opens the form but without data:

```
$("#update").button().click(function() {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
});
```

- All this stuff are working properly.
  How can I pass dog's data to the form to be shown? As you probably saw, I have a set of "dog" objects in SessionScope. Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery has a [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/%20.val%28%29) function that should do what you want.